# Авторизация в squid только при обращении к определенному адресу

Tags: squid, proxy, linux

Возможно ли сделать авторизацию в squid только если клиент обращается к определенному адресу? Если да, то как?

Comment: а почему нельзя авторизоваться для всех адресов?

Comment: открытое прокси, но нужно защитить что бы люди не заходили с него на один ресурс.

Comment: Простите, но прозрачный прокси должен быть либо прозрачным либо нет, третьего не дано. Либо защищайте ресурс прямо на нем, либо делайте авторизацию на все, все остальное - костыли.

Comment: Вы правы конечно правы, костыли. Но хотел временное решение, именно как костыль, думал вдруг есть.

Comment: Нет ничего более постоянного чем временное)

Answer (score 1):

`acl restricted_site dstdomain .somedomain.ru`

`acl users proxy_auth user1 user2` или `acl users external nt_group squid_users`, смотря как настроено.

`http_access allow restricted_site users
http_access allow all`